# UPDATE and SELECT - Using the table called from update in the select query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Here is a sample query:

```
UPDATE `table1` 
   SET `table1`.`field1` = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                              FROM `table2` 
                             WHERE `table2`.`field2` = `table1`.`field2`)
```

MySQL gives me an error message that `table1`.`field2` does not found.
Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's easier to understand with a less abstract example.

### `materials` table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `materials` (
  `material_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `qty` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`material_id`)
)
```

### `part_materials` table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parts` (
  `part_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `material_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`part_id`,`material_id`)
)
```

To update materials.qty with number of parts using that material:

`update materials set qty=(select count(*) from part_materials where material_id=materials.material_id)`